# Analysis, showing that something is equal 0

Tags: analysis

Sorry, for the title, but I'm not native English speaker, and actually, I have no idea how to name it in my own language.

So, I have

$\left[-x^{4}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}$

And I need to show that it is equal to $0$

But it is actually is?

Comment: What does the brackets with infinities mean?

Comment: @kingW3 They usually mean to evaluate the expression within at the upper value and subtract the expression evaluated at the lower value, so: $$[x]_{a}^{b}=b-a$$

Comment: Adam: when you find an answer(s) to be helpful, we encourage users to *accept one* answer found to be most helpful. (You can only accept one answer per question asked.) To accept an answer, you simply click on the gray $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. It turns green when you click on it, and you receive two reputation points each time you accept an answer to a question you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

This is like evaluating at the limits as $ x\to\infty $
The exponential will win over $ x^4 $ hence both evaluation will be zero which gives $0-0 $

Comment: well, actually I thought the same, but I was mislead by confusing it with integrals, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Well it is the result of an integral. But talking about infinity is like taking the limit